# How to make nginx behind reverse proxy allow access based on IP address from different header

Tags: nginx

I am trying to allow access to specific location of my website only for specific IP address.

I have two servers: load balancer with nginx and app server with nginx as well.
I am trying to allow requests to some location based on client's IP address.
For debugging, I added logging of headers to application and here is what I see there (i.e. I guess reverse proxy correctly transfers real client IP address):

```
"REMOTE_ADDR": "load.balancer.ip.address",
"HTTP_X_REAL_IP": "real.client.ip.address",
```

So I added location directive to nginx as follows:

```
location /upload  {
        allow real.client.ip.address;
        deny  all;
        alias /path/to/upload/folder;
}
```

Now when I try to access location `/upload/something` in browser, I see error 403 by nginx.
But when I remove `deny all` directive or change `real.client.ip.address` to `load.balancer.ip.address` I am able to access the location successfully.

How can I force nginx to check client's IP address in different header when it decides to `allow` or `deny`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use directives `set_real_ip_from` and `real_ip_header` as suggested in [Dusan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145196/dusan-bajic). But for some reason directives `allow` and `deny` still behaved as if I didn't replace real ip address.

So I used [geo module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) instead

```
geo $http_x_real_ip $is_not_from_office {
    default        1;

    allowed.ip.address.xxx      0;
}
```

I've put `$http_x_real_ip` as first argument because real ip was contained in `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` header.

Then I edited location in nginx configuration as follows:

```
location /upload  {
    if ($is_not_from_office) {
        return 403;
    }
    alias /path/to/upload/directory;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your appserver nginx `location`:

```
# Defines trusted addresses that are known to send correct replacement addresses
set_real_ip_from ip.of.load.balancer;

# Defines the request header field whose value will be used to replace the client address.
real_ip_header X-Whatever-Header-Holds-Real-IP;
```